# Filtering sellers and their location in detail

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am going to ask you for help,in this part the solution is complicated for me, the seller's location filter, I have two fields where I filter the seller and the other is to filter the locations that the selected seller has, however, it is not filtering, it always shows me empty. Here I attach the images and the code of the filter.

first image, the two fields that I have added are two that are highlighted:

[image]

second image: here I show the seller filter and the other should filter the location of the seller that I am selecting.

[image]

Here is my code to filter seller and location fields:

```
public class INTranExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.IN.INTran>
{
    #region UsrVendorID
    [PXDBInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Vendor")]
    [PXSelector(
    typeof(Search2<BAccountR.bAccountID,
    InnerJoin<Vendor, On<Vendor.bAccountID, Equal<BAccountR.bAccountID>>>>),
        typeof(BAccountR.acctCD),
        typeof(BAccountR.defLocationID),
        SubstituteKey = typeof(BAccountR.acctCD),DescriptionField = typeof(BAccountR.acctCD))]
    public virtual int? UsrVendorID { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrVendorID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrVendorID> { }
    #endregion

    #region UsrVendLocation
    [PXDBInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Vendor Location")]
    [PXSelector(
      typeof(Search<Location.locationID,
       Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Current<usrVendorID>>>>), 
       typeof(Location.locationCD),
       typeof(Location.descr), 
       SubstituteKey = typeof(Location.locationCD),
        DescriptionField = typeof(Location.descr))]

    public virtual int? UsrVendLocation { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrVendLocation : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrVendLocation> { }
    #endregion 
 }
```

image as I have called on the screen:

[image]

My English is not that good, I hope I have been clear.

Comment: The code and configuration look correct, have you tried to unpublished the package and publish it with cleanup? I have faced situations when the control in the UI is not always corresponding to the published package.

Comment: Hi Tibu, please make sure Vendor lookup has Commit Changes property turned on and in Vendor Locations the AutoRefresh Turned On in Ext Properties.

Comment: Hi Diegoapereza,
thanks for your answer, what you just mentioned if you have it all. as such is shown in the picture,